# How NFT marketplaces detect NFTs metadata updated?

Tags: go-ethereum, nft, erc-721, opensea

I have learned ERC-4906 to notify updating metadata.
I found out the way to detect some NFTs metadata updated, but I don't know how marketplace detect tremendous NFTs metadata updated.
Please let me know it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking they have background jobs which scrape the whole blockchain from block #1 to the latest and every newly added one.

A mutation of an NTF's metadata would be a transaction in a block. They detect it and save to their DB.

Yes, that's a pretty big setup of backend queues, workers, parsers and a huge Document-style DB (like Mongo).